# Change multiple permanent for() statements into only required for() statements required from user input

Tags: c, for-loop, base64

I am trying to make a c program that cycles through base64 symbols. And I did technically manage to achieve that. However, for each symbol, there is a specific for() statement. And I want it so that I can give it (not yet, only until I can get the code to work) user input (through arguments, but that's for later).

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BASE64_CHARS "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/"

int main() {
  int i, j, k, l, m, a;
    char base64[100];
    int base64_len = strlen(BASE64_CHARS);
    for (i = 0; i < base64_len; i++) {
        base64[0] = BASE64_CHARS[i];
        for (j = 0; j < base64_len; j++) {
            base64[1] = BASE64_CHARS[j];
            for (k = 0; k < base64_len; k++) {
                base64[2] = BASE64_CHARS[k];
                for (l = 0; l < base64_len; l++) {
                    base64[3] = BASE64_CHARS[l];
                    for (m = 0; m < base64_len; m++) {
                        base64[4] = BASE64_CHARS[m];
                        for (a = 0; a < base64_len; a++) {
                            base64[5] = BASE64_CHARS[a];
                            printf("\r%s", base64);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Any ideas on how to do this would be appreciated.

Comment: What kind of user input? A specific length?

Comment: Aside: this program invokes [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/behavior), as `base64` is not null-terminated.

Comment: There is no user input in your program.  To get well defined behavior you need to `char base64[100] = { 0 };`.

Comment: You are printing 64^6 (68719476736) strings which will take a while.  What's the point?

Comment: You'll be continually overwriting your output because of the `\r` in the format string, at least every time you fill the buffer.  The output will probably be a little odd, at any rate.

Comment: Instead of 6 nested loops, you need an array of 6 indexes into the Base 64 char string (call it `int index[6] = { 0 };`).  You initialize the array with zeros; you initialize elements 0 to 5 of `base64[]` with `A`'s and a null byte.  You increment `index[5]`; if it is less than 64, you put `BASE64_CHARS[index[5]]` into `base64[5]` and print; if it is equal to 64, you reset `index[5]` to 0 and increment `index[4]` — if that reaches 64, you reset it to zero and increment `index[3]`, etc., repeating until `index[0]` reaches 64 whereupon you stop, having enumerated all possibilities.

Comment: I recommend doing it with a string of 4 characters (instead of 64 characters), using a newline at the end of the format string, as that will allow you to see the behaviour.  Then reconfigure your code to use the bigger array.  This uses a single loop (that runs a lot of iterations) to drive the main processing; there's an auxilliary loop inside to deal with the 'increment and carry' processing.  You can work right to left (as outlined, and as illustrated by your code) or left to right.

Comment: Are you aware of the concept of recursion?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you use an array to emulate an arbitrary number of base 64 digits counter.  Then you just need a function `incr()` to add `1` to the counter with carry, `print()` function to convert your counter to a string, and for generality a `done()` function to detect when at the maximum value.

Below I used a 2 digit counter `{ [1] = 0 }` which is just fancy way of saying index 1 should be 0 and the ones not specified are zero-initialized.  To use a 6 digit counter you would use `{ [5] = 0 }`.

`strlen(BASE64_CHARS) == sizeof BASE64_CHARS - 1` but the latter is computed at compile-time.

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BASE64_CHARS "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/"
#define BASE64_LEN sizeof BASE64_CHARS - 1

// The most significant digit is at index 0, and the the least
// significant digit at index n-1
void incr(size_t n, unsigned char counter[n]) {
    assert(n);
    for(size_t i = n - 1;; i--) {
        if(counter[i] < BASE64_LEN - 1) {
            counter[i]++;
            break;
        }
        counter[i] = 0;
        // carry over ends at the most significant digit
        if(!i) 
            break;
    }
}

int done(size_t n, unsigned char counter[n]) {
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        if(counter[i] < BASE64_LEN - 1)
            return 0;
    return 1;
}

void print(size_t n, unsigned char counter[n]) {
    for(size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("%c", BASE64_CHARS[counter[i]]);
    printf("\n");
}

int main(void) {
    unsigned char counter[] = { [1] = 0 };
    size_t counter_len = sizeof counter / sizeof *counter;
    for(;;) {
        print(counter_len, counter);
        if(done(counter_len, counter))
            break;
        incr(counter_len, counter);
    }
}
```

and here the first and last few lines:

```
AA
AB
...
/+
//
```

Comment: If that answered your question please accept it by clicking on the check mark next to it.  That way we know you are all set.